# Is Java TreeSet and HashSet expected to give different result with the same data?

Tags: java, hashset, treeset

The Following program prints 
one|two
one|two
when HashSet is used. If I change it to TreeSet it prints only
one|two

Is it not expected to give the same result with the same set of data ?What am I doing wrong here? What in the program makes the second record duplicate in case of TreeSet?

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

```
public class SetTest {

public static void main(String arg[]) {
    Set<Bk> bookList = new HashSet<Bk>();
            //Set<Bk> bookList = new TreeSet<Bk>();
    bookList.add(new Bk("one","two"));
    bookList.add(new Bk("one","two"));
    for(Bk book: bookList){
        System.out.println(book);
    }
}
}

class Bk implements Comparable<Bk> {


public String name;
public String author;

public String toString(){
    return name+"|"+ author;
}

Bk(String name, String author) {
    this.name = name;
    this.author = author;

}

@Override
public int compareTo(Bk that) {

    int author = this.author.compareTo(that.author);
    int name = 0;
    if (author == 0) {
        name = this.name.compareTo(that.name);
        return name;
    } else {
        return author;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please always read the javadoc of the classes involved before posting.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I edited the question to format the code; `<Bk>` wasn't showing up on `Comparable` until I formatted it.  Now the `compareTo` method's `Bk` parameter makes sense.

Comment: `hashCode` and `equals` are missing....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `HashSet` class will use `hashCode` and `equals` to determine if there is a duplicate already in the set.  The `TreeSet` class will use the fact that it's `Comparable` (or alternatively, a `Comparator`) to order items and determine if there's a duplicate.

You have `Bk` as `Comparable<Bk>`, so `TreeSet` will work properly with it.  But, you still need to override `hashCode` and `equals` so `HashSet` will work properly with it also.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation... I was getting consistent result overriding equals and hashCode.. Was not aware TreeSet and HashSet rely on different methods for checking duplicates...

Answer (score 2):

If you want consistent behaviour with a HashSet you would have to implement hashCode() and equals(), as per the Javadoc, and in such a way as to be consistent with your compareTo() method.